# Definite Integral that Evaluates to Teacher's Initials: TAA

Tags: definite-integrals, recreational-mathematics

My school's calculus teacher's birthday is in a couple of days, and our class decided to give him a surprise birthday card that has a definite integral which evaluates to his initials (TAA). So far all we can think of are easy integrands, and we're stumped even when we tried ones which evaluate to $TA^{2}$ (sorry for my lack of math typography knowledge on this site). He's a really great teacher and it would mean a lot if anyone could help find such an integral. If possible, please keep the difficulty down to a moderate level like integration by parts twice or partial fractions as a relatively hard difficulty level so it won't take too much time to solve it.
Any help is much appreciated.
(PS: I'm relatively new to this site so my apologies if I radically broke the etiquette here.)

Comment: Do you mean you are looking for something like
$$
\int_0^a 2tx dx = ta^2
$$
except more complex?

Comment: Yes, in fact that was exactly what we came up with :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The circle with radius $\sqrt{\frac{T}{\pi}}A$ has area $TA^2$. This circle can be described by the equation $x^2 + y^2 = \frac{T}{\pi}A^2$, so the upper semicircle is described by the function $y = \sqrt{\frac{T}{\pi}A^2 - x^2}$. Therefore,
$$
4\int_0^{\sqrt{\frac{T}{\pi}}A}\sqrt{\frac{T}{\pi}A^2 - x^2} dx = TA^2.
$$

A more artistic version of the same concept might be to color a circle and simply indicate in your picture that the radius is $\sqrt{\frac{T}{\pi}}A$. That way the entire class can stare at him until he does the obvious computation. This also sidesteps the rather unfortunate fact that my integral has the string "$TA^2$" right there in the integrand.